# SOQL - APEX - List

Tags: list, apex-code, custom-fields, soql

*Hello Folks,*
            *I have a list which has values from a query. The list has multiple fields, how can I access a specific field from this list?*

**Problem:**

```
List <Account> listS = [Select 
                         (Select S__c from AS__r 
                         where S__r.Abc__c = 'Confirmed'), 
                         (Select PQR__c from AHS__r) 
                       from Account where Id in: TravellerIds];

List <AS__c> listAS = new list <AS__c>();
for (Account t: listS){
    listAS.add(t.AS__r);
}
```

**Problem in pseudocode**:
For (every Account in listS)
{
   ListAS.add(S__c field from the listS);
}

I have tried what I mentioned in the Problem section but I am unable to access it. Please help me.

**Error that I get is this** : List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject.

Thanks a lot for the help.

**Note: I do not want to access the S_*c field inside the for loop for every AS*_c.. I want to access it for every Account.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're querying a parent child relationship the field `t.AS__r` on the Account object is actually a list of the objects that meet the sub query criteria. Therefore all you need to do is change `listAS.add(t.AS__r);` to be `listAS.addAll(t.AS__r);` and this will make your example code work - adding all of the items returned in the sub query to your new list.

By extension if you wanted to add all the S_*c fields, as you say in your pseudo code, then all you need to do is loop through the sub query list for each account and add the S*_c field to a list like so:

```
List<string> listOfS = new List<string>();
for(Account acc : listAS){
  for(A__c a: acc.AS__r){
     listOfS.add(a.S__c);
  }
}
```

This presumes that your custom object referred to by the relationship name `AS__r` has an API name of `A__c` and that the field `S__c` is of type string - but hopefully you get the idea.

Does this help?